# Custom Java app, does not show startup splash screen on some devices?

Tags: windows-10, java, dll, c

I have a Java app, called Infra12. It is not for sale so wont be in common use. It is designed to interrogate industrial equipment, but the supplier of the software has gone into administration, and they only supplied it to customers who bought industrial equipment from them - one of them being us. This app contains JRE within it, so it should run without JRE being installed on the machines themselves - none of the devices I have tested it on have JRE installed.

I have a problem with this app, which I cannot solve. When I run it, on some machines it will show the startup splash screen, thereby letting me enter the product key so I can enable it. However, on other machines this startup splash screen does not show.

Machines I have tested this on where it works:

> HP Prodesk 400 G5 PC, Win 10 Pro 1803 17134.407, x64, i5-8500 3.0GHz,
>   16GB RAM, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1GB, 1920x1080
>
> Xiaomi Mi 13 Air laptop, Win 10 Pro 1809 17763.194, x64, i5-6200u
>   2.3GHz, 8GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 520 1GB / Nvidia Geforce 940MX 1GB, 1920x1080
>
> Acer Revo One RL85 PC, Win 7 Pro 7601 6.1.7601, x86, Celeron 2957u
>   1.4GHz, 4GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics, 1600x900

Machines I have tested this on where it doesnt work:

> HP Envyx360 laptop, Win 10 Home 1803 17134.407, x64, i7-7500u 2.7GHz,
>   8GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 620 1GB / Nvidia Geforce MX 940MX 1GB,
>   1920x1080
>
> Surface Pro 4 DESKTOP-LR0D2QT laptop, Win 10 Pro 1809 17763.194, x64,
>   i7-6650u 2.2GHz, 8GB RAM, Intel Iris 540 1GB, 1920x1080
>
> Dell Vostro 5468 laptop, Win 10 Pro 1809 17763.194, x64, i5-7200u
>   2.5GHz, 8GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 620 1GB, 1366x768

I have tried to run it using CMD prompt on the non working machines, and have managed to get an error log generated by the app, which I cannot decipher:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION (0xe06d7363) at pc=0x75551812, pid=9356, tid=11752
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x111812]  RaiseException+0x62
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0306ac00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11752, stack(0x02e30000,0x02e80000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe06d7363, ExceptionInformation=0x19930520 0x02e7f31c 0x682d8b30 

Registers:
EAX=0x02e7f278, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000003, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x02e7f278, EBP=0x02e7f2d4, ESI=0x02e7f388, EDI=0x02e7f388
EIP=0x75551812, EFLAGS=0x00000216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x02e7f278)
0x02e7f278:   e06d7363 00000001 00000000 75551812
0x02e7f288:   00000003 19930520 02e7f31c 682d8b30
0x02e7f298:   00000000 77812540 00000000 00000000
0x02e7f2a8:   00000000 00000001 00000000 777e22d3
0x02e7f2b8:   02e7f398 0139b430 00000000 00000000
0x02e7f2c8:   00000001 8a23608d 00000009 02e7f30c
0x02e7f2d8:   684a7819 e06d7363 00000001 00000003
0x02e7f2e8:   02e7f300 e06d7363 00000001 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x75551812)
0x755517f2:   89 44 24 10 c1 e0 02 50 51 8d 44 24 1c 50 e8 0f
0x75551802:   85 00 00 83 c4 0c 8d 04 24 50 ff 15 9c 33 5f 75
0x75551812:   8b 4c 24 54 33 cc e8 f3 43 00 00 8b e5 5d c2 10
0x75551822:   00 83 64 24 10 00 eb de 6a 0f 58 eb c3 cc cc cc 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x02e7f278 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0306ac00
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000003 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x02e7f278 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0306ac00
EBP=0x02e7f2d4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0306ac00
ESI=0x02e7f388 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0306ac00
EDI=0x02e7f388 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0306ac00


Stack: [0x02e30000,0x02e80000],  sp=0x02e7f278,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x111812]  RaiseException+0x62
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x27819]  CxxThrowException+0x45
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x2cf0]
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x2c81]
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x2b7b]
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x3cbd]  helperFunction2+0x28d
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x43ec]  helperFunction1+0xfc
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x6cb9]  Java_com_schindler_softguard_SoftGuard_function8+0x149
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x6e9f]  function2+0x3f
C  [SoftGuard.dll+0x7090]  Java_com_schindler_softguard_SoftGuard_function2+0x10
j  com.schindler.softguard.SoftGuard.function2(II)J+0
j  com.schindler.cadi.general.Drive.getNbrOfDaysLeft()J+7
j  com.schindler.cadi.general.StartupLogo.generateEndDate()V+0
j  com.schindler.cadi.general.StartupLogo.<init>(Z)V+54
j  com.schindler.cadi.main.CadiGC.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+13
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x12b41a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1daa0e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12b49d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xaf3f4]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb9777]
C  [java.exe+0x205f]
C  [java.exe+0xa5a1]
C  [java.exe+0xa62b]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x18484]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6302c]  RtlValidSecurityDescriptor+0x11c
C  [ntdll.dll+0x62ffa]  RtlValidSecurityDescriptor+0xea

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.schindler.softguard.SoftGuard.function2(II)J+0
j  com.schindler.cadi.general.Drive.getNbrOfDaysLeft()J+7
j  com.schindler.cadi.general.StartupLogo.generateEndDate()V+0
j  com.schindler.cadi.general.StartupLogo.<init>(Z)V+54
j  com.schindler.cadi.main.CadiGC.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+13
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x194a1800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=980, stack(0x19af0000,0x19b40000)]
  0x194a1000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=1516, stack(0x19a10000,0x19a60000)]
  0x194d6800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1116, stack(0x19980000,0x199d0000)]
  0x193c7800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10164, stack(0x19770000,0x197c0000)]
  0x193c2000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4868, stack(0x196e0000,0x19730000)]
  0x193c0c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12108, stack(0x19650000,0x196a0000)]
  0x193be800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11944, stack(0x195c0000,0x19610000)]
  0x02fe1c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11796, stack(0x19330000,0x19380000)]
  0x02fdd000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12000, stack(0x192a0000,0x192f0000)]
=>0x0306ac00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11752, stack(0x02e30000,0x02e80000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02fd7800 VMThread [stack: 0x19210000,0x19260000] [id=11736]
  0x193dc400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x19800000,0x19850000] [id=4052]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 1993K [0x050f0000, 0x05640000, 0x0a640000)
  eden space 4416K,  45% used [0x050f0000, 0x052e2780, 0x05540000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x05540000, 0x05540000, 0x055c0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x055c0000, 0x055c0000, 0x05640000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x0a640000, 0x0b0f0000, 0x150f0000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x0a640000, 0x0a640000, 0x0a640200, 0x0b0f0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 4020K [0x150f0000, 0x15cf0000, 0x190f0000)
   the space 12288K,  32% used [0x150f0000, 0x154dd028, 0x154dd200, 0x15cf0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x190f0000,0x191a0000] byte_map_base: 0x190c7880

Polling page: 0x02e90000

Code Cache  [0x03070000, 0x03118000, 0x05070000)
 total_blobs=211 nmethods=38 adapters=108 free_code_cache=32099Kb largest_free_block=32869952

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x193c2000   34             java.util.HashMap::indexFor (6 bytes)
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x193c2000 nmethod 34 0x031155c8 code [0x031156c0, 0x03115730]
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x193c2000   35             java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapIterator::hasNext (50 bytes)
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x193c2000 nmethod 35 0x03115788 code [0x03115880, 0x03115960]
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x193c2000   36             java.util.HashMap$HashIterator::nextEntry (99 bytes)
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x193c2000 nmethod 36 0x03115a08 code [0x03115b30, 0x03115d48]
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x193c2000   37             java.util.HashMap::hash (59 bytes)
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x193c2000 nmethod 37 0x03115f08 code [0x03116020, 0x03116198]
Event: 0.111 Thread 0x193c2000   38             java.util.HashMap::transfer (115 bytes)
Event: 0.111 Thread 0x193c2000 nmethod 38 0x031166c8 code [0x031167e0, 0x031169dc]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.067 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x05227848 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.067 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x05227960 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.069 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x05229358 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:716
Event: 0.084 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052453d0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:716
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052a0988 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052a0ea0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052a6538 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052a6a50 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.114 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052c4828 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 0.117 Thread 0x0306ac00 Threw 0x052cd738 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u21\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.114 loading class 0x02f150a0
Event: 0.114 loading class 0x02f150a0 done
Event: 0.114 loading class 0x1947ab90
Event: 0.114 loading class 0x1947ab90 done
Event: 0.115 loading class 0x02f15688
Event: 0.115 loading class 0x02f15688 done
Event: 0.115 loading class 0x02faa9a0
Event: 0.115 loading class 0x02faa9a0 done
Event: 0.117 loading class 0x1a402fd8
Event: 0.117 loading class 0x1a402fd8 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00db0000 - 0x00ddf000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\java.exe
0x777a0000 - 0x77930000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x74b60000 - 0x74c40000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x75440000 - 0x75624000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x6e8c0000 - 0x6e95d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x747d0000 - 0x74848000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x74670000 - 0x7472f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x772c0000 - 0x77304000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x75380000 - 0x75440000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x74060000 - 0x74080000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SspiCli.dll
0x74050000 - 0x7405a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76980000 - 0x769d8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x741c0000 - 0x7434d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x740e0000 - 0x740f7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x76bc0000 - 0x76be2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x76c40000 - 0x76da4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x74130000 - 0x741ad000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x77470000 - 0x7758e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x6f580000 - 0x6f784000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17134.407_none_42f1d43a44dfbaef\COMCTL32.dll
0x743b0000 - 0x7460c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x74100000 - 0x74126000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x68480000 - 0x6853e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x77cb0000 - 0x77fff000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x77340000 - 0x77346000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6ecc0000 - 0x6ecc8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x6e1a0000 - 0x6e1c4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x769e0000 - 0x76a47000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x6e170000 - 0x6e193000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x77430000 - 0x77469000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x68470000 - 0x6847c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x68450000 - 0x68470000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\java.dll
0x68430000 - 0x68443000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x682e0000 - 0x68422000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x752e0000 - 0x75376000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x6b5f0000 - 0x6b613000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x6e780000 - 0x6e7fc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x76a50000 - 0x76b93000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x77590000 - 0x7768c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x747c0000 - 0x747cf000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x75630000 - 0x7697a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x77350000 - 0x773d8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x74d20000 - 0x752d9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76c35000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x77690000 - 0x776a8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x773e0000 - 0x77425000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x77320000 - 0x77328000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL
0x682d0000 - 0x682de000     C:\Program Files (x86)\cadi_gc\SoftGuard.dll
0x6e840000 - 0x6e8a9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP100.dll
0x74730000 - 0x747b3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x71f60000 - 0x71f6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll
0x71ef0000 - 0x71f5b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll
0x735b0000 - 0x735c9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x70210000 - 0x70220000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
0x6fde0000 - 0x6fea3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll
0x6e990000 - 0x6eb12000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: cadigc.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Jacob Hall\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
USERNAME=J Hat
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8 , 64 bit Build 9200 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8258212k(4763484k free), swap 16646820k(12516480k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.21-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_21-b11), built on Apr  4 2013 04:43:10 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Dec 11 11:41:20 2018
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

If anyone can help, or point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful

Comment: Here you may find a solution to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448163/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-libjvm

Comment: The question was resolved on that link, but no reason given as to the cause or what the fix was or anything. :(

Comment: hmm but there are few other answers that might be helpful in your case as it's not coming on a specific hardware, and I found in your description that you are running the same os on the executed and not executed machines, the error details too doesn't show anything specific to provide a solution you may contact to the people who built it.

Comment: Sadly the people who built it are not available any more